# What is the order of operations for $p \implies q \implies r$

Tags: logic

I've been studying mathematical logic recently and we have briefly covered the order of operations for operators like AND/OR/IMPLIES, etc.

However, we have a challenge question regarding how the following statement should be interpreted in terms of order of operations, and I don't believe we have covered this material nor can I find the same question answered online.

The statement is
$p \implies q \implies r$

The question asks if the above statement is correctly represented by $(p \implies q) \implies r$, or $p \implies (q \implies r)$, or neither - i.e. what is the correct order of operations when there are no brackets and the two logic operators are equally weighted.

I have used a truth table to determine that the above two statements are not equivalent, but are either the logical equivalent to the first statement, or neither?

Comment: This is a weird challenge question, if they're asking you to parse an expression for which they haven't given you all the parsing rules.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that $p \to (q \to r)$ (the almost certain intended meaning as covered in MauroAllegranza's answer) is the same as $(p \land q) \to r$

Answer (score 5):

The usual convention for omitting parentheses (see e.g. Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic, Academic Press (2nd ed. 2001)](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA33)) is:

> 1. The outermost parentheses need not be explicitly mentioned.
> 2. The negation symbol applies to as little as possible.
> 3. The conjunction and disjunction symbols apply to as little as possible.
> 4. Where one connective symbol is used repeatedly, grouping is to
>    the right.

Thus, $p \to q \to r$ must be read as:

> $p \to (q \to r)$.

*But every convention may be checked with the formal specifications of the language used in your textbook.*

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the purposes of your course (or if you were to see it in a paper specifically on logic) may be different, but in general mathematical usage this is shorthand for "$p\Rightarrow q$ and $q\Rightarrow r$", similar to constructs like $a\leq b\leq c$.

(If something other than this is meant, I think parentheses should always be used.)

Comment: I have not seen this in general mathematical usage, and I think it would be risky to read it in that way.

Comment: Unfortunately that is an informal useage to highlight a chain of inference between a series of bullet points. It is something which has to be unlearned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how widely used it is, but I find the following convention to be the most natural and convenient:

**Descending Order of Precedence for Logical Operators**

1. Innermost most brackets from left to right
2. NOT ($\neg$) from right to left
3. AND ($\land$) from left to right
4. OR ($\lor$) from left to right
5. IMPLIES ($\implies$) from left to right
6. IFF ($\iff$) from left to right

**Examples**

1. $P\implies Q \implies R$
   would be interpreted as $[P\implies Q ]\implies R$.
2. $A\land B\space \lor  C \land \neg D$ would be interpreted as
   $[A\land B] \lor [ C \land [\neg D]]$.

But, as Mauro said, "Every convention may be checked with the formal specifications of the language used in your textbook."

Comment: Usually $p \to q \to r$ is read as $p \to (q \to r)$ instead. This is related to the Curry-Howard isomorphism and the equivalence with $(p \land q) \to r$.

Comment: @CarlMummert So, you make an exception for IMPLIES under that convention. I guess, grouping left or right doesn't matter for AND, OR and IFF since they are associative; IMPLIES is not.